# Dynamic Code Evaluation: JNDI Reference Injection Logging unmarshalled object

Tags: java, jndi, resttemplate, unmarshalling, fortify

I have a code like below, unfortunately fortify scan reports a JNDI reference injection here. How could that happen for a unmarshalled java object?

```
var response = restTemplate.exchange("url", HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
var customModel = mapper.readValue(response.getBody(), CustomModel.class);
log.debug("Response from provider, {}", customModel.toString());
```

Comment: Currently, I have the same issue and all log statements, e.g. `logger.info("My name is {}", name);` in which there is a variable used, Fortify complaints. All this despite the fact that these are not variables which contain user input data.